# Svelte and sortablejs : issues with dynamic list

Tags: svelte, sortablejs

I have a similar problem as the one shown in this Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9fe76dda194348d1acd6d2e336c30c22?version=3.35.0).

If I create a **sortablejs** object in a Svelte project from a dynamic list (that means a list created with `{#each...}` logic blocks from a dynamic variable - `stages` in the example), the job is done regarding the `stages` variable (objects are moved correctly in the array) but the display is not correct after the move.

My guess is :

- **sortablejs** attaches tags to an item of the list `foo` when it's created
- moving the order on the HTML list triggers the move on the `stages` array as expected
- items order in the HTML list change because this `foo` list is bind to the `stages` array
- as the order changed in this HTML list, the sortablejs tags order changes as well.

It's like the move happened once in the `stages` array and twice in the `foo` list.

What I expect is that, after a move, the order of the `foo` HTML list would be the same as the order of the `stages` array.

I didn't find how to solve this issue. Any help/hind appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**

I thought the REPL was releavant enough to explain my problem but it was not. The key point of this issue is not the use of `{#each...}` but the fact that `stages` is dynamic.

Here is the code I working with :

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Sortable from "sortablejs"
  import ChipExo from "./ChipExo.svelte"
  import { exercicesParams, moveExercice } from "../store"
  import { onMount } from "svelte"

  let listIdsForChips: string[] = []
  $: {
    listIdsForChips = []
    for (const ex of $exercicesParams) {
      listIdsForChips.push(ex.id ?? ex.uuid)
    }
    listIdsForChips = listIdsForChips
  }
  let chipsList: HTMLDivElement
  onMount(() => {
    chipsList = document.getElementById("chips-list")
    const sortable = Sortable.create(chipsList, {
      animation: 150,
      onEnd: (evt) => {
        exercicesParams.update((l) => {
          return moveExercice(l, evt.oldIndex, evt.newIndex)
        })
      },
    })
  })
</script>

<div
  class="w-full grid justify-items-stretch place-content-stretch grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-7 xl:grid-cols-8 2xl:grid-cols-10 gap-2 p-0 items-center overflow-x-auto whitespace-nowrap"
  id="chips-list"
>
  {#each listIdsForChips as id, indice (indice)}
    <ChipExo text={id} {indice} />
  {/each}
</div>
```

and here is the display in HTML

[Chips List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZwja.png)

The `listIdsForChips` variable is reset every time the `exercicesParams` store changes. For example, Chips can be removed by clicking on the close icon of the chip. So the `listIdsForChips` variable **has to be dynamic**.

I hope this edit will clarify the issue.

Comment: A link to a Repl is fine, but the question should also include all relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example `stages` doesn't depend on any other value, so just `let stages = ...` without reactive declaration

When adding a key to the `#each` block it seems to be working correctly - [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)

```html
{#each stages as stage (stage.data)}
  <li>{stage.data}</li>
{/each}
```

In your second example, instead of setting the index as key

```
{#each listIdsForChips as id, indice (indice)}
    <ChipExo text={id} {indice} />
{/each}
```

since you map to the id or uuid take the value instead

```
{#each listIdsForChips as id, indice (id)}
    <ChipExo text={id} {indice} />
{/each}
```

or if there's no unique field - from the [tutorial explanation](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)

> You can use any object as the key, as Svelte uses a Map internally — in other words you could do (thing) instead of (thing.id). Using a string or number is generally safer, however, since it means identity persists without referential equality, for example when updating with fresh data from an API server.

The second problem with the reactive statements seems to be with the first line - changing to a second variable name seems to be one fix

```
 let listIdsForChips: string[] = []
  $: {
    let lIFC = []
    for (const ex of $exercicesParams) {
      lIFC.push(ex.id ?? ex.uuid)
    }
    listIdsForChips = lIFC
  }
```

To reduce unpredicted behaviour and make the dependencies clearer, wrapping in a function is an alternative way

```
let listIdsForChips: string[] = []

$: updateListIdsForChips($exercicesParams)

function updateListIdsForChips(eP) {
    let lIFC = []
    for (const ex of eP) {
      lIFC.push(ex.id ?? ex.uuid)
    }
    listIdsForChips = lIFC
}
```

or in this case reducing to one line

```
 let listIdsForChips: string[] = []
 $: listIdsForChips = $exercicesParams.map(p => p.id ?? p.uuid)
```

I updated the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0e6df004e68f4ecf95fcfbb7d26e0ea2?version=3.35.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think that the point here is that `stages` variable _may_ evolve in real situation (that why it has been set up dynamic) by removing/adding items to it.
So what to do in this case ? That's the real question and I'm truthfully sorry about my unclarity here.

Comment: @SylvainChambon Modifications work with a `let` https://svelte.dev/repl/0e6df004e68f4ecf95fcfbb7d26e0ea2?version=3.35.0 A Reactive statement is needed/used when the value depends on other values https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations (The main point in your example is the key of the #each block)

Comment: I have edit my initial post: I *need* a reactive statement in my code. I thought the REPL was simple enough to explain my issue... Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Your first idea (use `id` instead of `indice`) was almost enough to address the issue. The fact that one exercise uuid can occur several times in the `$exercicesParams` variable, I use your idea this way.
`{#each listIdsForChips as id, indice (id + indice)}`
And implement your last idea as weel. It works like a charm now. Thanks !